# Library Permissions

Tags: library, item-level-permissions

I have a standard library with a number of files in it; my user can access all the files in the folder.

I added a new file to the library and for some unknown reason the user cannot access the new file. I have not (not intentionally at least!) set up special permissions on this new file, as far as I can tell the file should have inherited the library permissions.

How can I check the permissions of the new file and compare to permissions of existing files?

Comment: Please check may be the file is in checked out mode. if check in then only the file is available for the other users to see.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say either the file has no checked in version or you have (unintentionally) mixed up the permissions.

To check for the first option go to the library's settings page and look under "Permissions and Management". If the file has no checked in version check in the file and it should be visible to your users.

[image]

To check for a specific files' permissions click the three dots next to a file, then on the other three dots and click "Shared With". Now click on "Advanced" and now you can check for the files permissions or check what permissions a specific user has.

[image]

[image]

[image]